# ad hoc app failed to install on real iPad

Tags: ios5

What follows applies **only to** Xcode 4.3.1 and 4.3.2, **but not earlier** versions.  Also, I have iOS 5.1 on my iPad.

My app, built with my ad-hoc provisioning profile, failed to install via iTunes on my real iPad.  In desperation, I have also tried my wild card profile, my app store release profile and my development profile ... still no install.

In an effort to also provide pictures for what I have, please take a look at the following:

1) Provisioning Profiles in the Finder:

http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/1.png

2) Xcode Target:

http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/2.png

3) Xcode Signing Identity popup:

http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/3.png

4) Xcode Organizer:

http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/4.png

Now, what's really weird is that if I refresh (via the icon in lower-right corner), the Ad Hoc Distribution and the App Store Release profiles disappear both in the Organizer and in the Finder folder "Provisioning Profiles".

5) Even with this disappearance, in my iOS Provisioning Portal all is intact:

http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/5.png

http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/6.png

[http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/7.png](http://webpages.charter.net/jolove/Forum_Graphics/6.png)

I really have been tackling this problem for over a week.  Other forums have said I have a problem with the Provisioning Profile.  I accept that, but I honestly do not know what the problem is, especially since the problem just surfaced with Xcode 4.3.

John Love

Comment: A horrible thought just occured to me.

Namely, I did update to Xcode 4.3.2

And, regular Software Update updated iTunes

BUT, I have the original iPad, not #2 or #3

Is THIS the cause, namely the older iPad.

Comment: With your permission, I would like to add one basic question ...

Has anyone at all successfully installed an Ad-Hoc app on their real device using Xcode 4.3.1 or 4.3.2 via the current version of iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At precisely 0726 hours on April 1st, I just successfully installed my Ad Hoc app on my real iPad.

**PROBLEM:**

1) had Entitlements.plist "get task allow" set to YES.

2) should have been NO for a Ad Hoc distribution

3) however, according to my very good friend, TN 2250:

You only need to specify a custom Code Signing Entitlements file if your application is utilizing custom keychain access sharing or iCloud

4) so, I deleted it from the Projects / Targets

**SUCCESS!**

P.S.  this is no joke, in spite of the date

John Love